# inputting decimals in ipad calc with objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I'm a complete novice to objective C/ipad development, but I am trying to build a simple four function calculator on the iPad.

My problem is trying to display a number with a decimal in it: i.e. 5.273 or .0021

My entire calculator is float, but when doing

```
[resultfield setText: NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lf", display]]
```

the output (say the one button was pressed) would be: *1.00000*. I know that if you change the format to @".0lf" all the extra zeroes will disappear and the output would be *1*

However, that doesn't help me when doing trying to input a decimal number, or when doing division. If I divide 10/3 the result would be displayed as 3 rather than 3.333333333

Any ideas on how to keep my numbers as float but not display trailing zeroes?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [NSNumberFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class. It will let you set rounding and truncation of your decimals.